# checkin if char in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to save a pandas `dataframe` as a `csv` file, but I have trouble finding a good separator : If I save the `dataframe` and load the saved filed, I have mixed columns.

So I need to check if some char are in my `dataframe` and would cause this issue.

I've tried :

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].str.contains("|",na=False):
        print df[df[col].str.contains(",",na=False)]
```

with "," being the wanted separator, but it returns :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

If I use `.any()` or `.all()`, it returns the whole `dataframe`. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: just use `df[col].str.contains("|",na=False).any()` in the `if` statement, but use `df[df[col].str.contains(",", na=False)]` in your print statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for check at least one `True` because compare `boolean Series`, not scalar values `True` or `False`:

```
if df[col].str.contains("|",na=False).any():
```